# Xcode 8 beta - Command Failed due to Signal: Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I recently got this error when I tried to run my project in Xcode.

I'm using Xcode 8 beta and this issue very rarely occurred even when using Xcode 7 but after a few times running it after it failed it ran fine.

> Showing Recent Errors Only
>
> MergeSwiftModule normal i386

1. While loading members for `MenuViewController` at invalid loc
2. While deserializing decl #127 (`PATTERN_BINDING_DECL`)
3. While deserializing decl #9 (`VAR_DECL`)

Comment: We'll need some more informations about the context. Please, take some times to read this: [ask].

Comment: The community has discussed [adding ASAP/deadline notes to questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495), and has firmly decided it is not acceptable. Please read!

Answer (score -2):

I was having the same issue and after trying many many things, my project compiled correctly.

After renaming back the application file to: `Xcode`, my project finally compiled.

Please note: I have previously named it `Xcode 8 GM` after downloading the application in order to differentiate it from the other `Xcode 7.3` already installed in my machine.

Of course, I did also try before:

- Cleaning the project
- Restarting the computer
- Deleting derived data
- Deleting `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` folder
- Doing `pod install` and `pod update` again and again

If you didn't rename the `Xcode` application maybe one of the steps mentioned before might be of your help.